# Ubuntu 14.04 "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa" error

Tags: ubuntu, repository, install, ppa

Пытаюсь установить Ubuntu Tweak, для этого добавляю репозиторий. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa . Terminal выдаёт ошибку:

```
     Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:tualatrix/ppa'.
`   `Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.
```

Как мне тогда установить Ubuntu Tweak через терминал?

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо экспортировать переменные среды прокси-сервера, используя:

```
export http_proxy=http://username:password@host:port/
export https_proxy=https://username:password@host:port/
```

а затем скажите sudo использовать их, используя:

```
sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
```

или откройте файл / etc / sudoers (используя sudo visudo) и добавьте:

```
Defaults env_keep="https_proxy"
```

до конца файла. Вот [ссылка](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452595/cannot-add-ppa-behind-proxy-ubuntu-14-04) на первоисточник.

Comment: А откуда взять username, password, host и port?

Comment: Ну я думаю юзернейм и пароль ваш, и порт тоже а хост это куда вы подключаться будете.

Comment: А куда мне надо подключаться, чтобы добавить репозиторий? Логин и пароль от чего?

Comment: я думаю что логин и пароль от вашей учетной записи линукс

Comment: Я уже ответила на свой вопрос. См. ниже.

Comment: да я видел, рад что у вас все получилось :)

Answer (score 0):

Отключила SplDer Gate и SplDer Guard и заработало.:)

Comment: А зачем антивирус в принципе был установлен?